# I have two dropdown menu with Angular Material in one component (one page) with different positions, and I want give unique classes to each

Tags: angular, angular-material

beacause of diffrent positions of my dropdowns i want to give diffrent top and left to them(with absolute position),,

first dropdown:

```
<div class="theme">
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger (menuClosed)="menuTrigger.focus()" aria-hidden="true">
        <mat-icon class="paint-format" svgIcon="core:paint-format"></mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
        <div>
            <span class="circle" (click)="toGreen()" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: green; margin: auto 4px;"></span>

            <span class="circle" (click)="toBlue()" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: blue; margin: auto 4px;"></span>

            <span class="circle" (click)="toDark()" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: brown; margin: auto 4px;"></span>
        </div>
    </mat-menu>
</div>
```

and second dropdown is:

```
<div class="smallTheme">
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger (menuClosed)="menuTrigger.focus()" aria-hidden="true">
        <mat-icon class="paint-format" svgIcon="core:paint-format"></mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" xPosition="before">
        <div>
            <span class="circle" (click)="toGreen()" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: green; margin: auto 4px;"></span>

            <span class="circle" (click)="toBlue()" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: blue; margin: auto 4px;"></span>

            <span class="circle" (click)="toDark()" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: brown; margin: auto 4px;"></span>
        </div>
    </mat-menu>
</div>
```

Can any one tell me how to distinguish them of each other to give diffrent css styles to?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving extra classes to your dropdowns you could access them via their parent components. For example

```
div.theme>button {
    ...
}
```

Would match only the button in the first snippet because it is a direct child of a div which has the `theme` class.

Similarly

```
div.smallTheme>button {
    ...
}
```

Would allow you to only edit the second button.

Comment: but it isn't possible, because dropdown tags after opening will create out of it's parent and before body end tag(</body>)!